# Remove trailing slash

Tags: url-rewriting, pagination, redirect

I need to revert from "pretty prmalinks" to query string just for the pagination urls.
(so that `example.com/page/2` becomes `example.com/?paged=2`).

It could possibly be done via a hook in to redirect canonical but I couldn't find a way (is there?)

Or it could be done with `$wp_rewrite->pagination_base = '?paged=';` but this adds a trailing slash after the slug, so I have becomes `example.com/?paged=/2`

(Update: Doing `$wp_rewrite->pagination_base = '?paged=%#%';` creates a working but redundant `example.com/?paged=2/2`)

How to remove that slash?

Comment: Can I ask why you need to do this? We might have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: ( Maybe just a bit of [OCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) on my part :D )
I just want to make sure that the pagination is not indexed even though i already use the respective meta tag.

Comment: Then yeah, you are being OCD ;) If you've got your `robots` handled, that's all you need. Why "dirty" up the URL's and (possibly) break navigation when there's no need? I stress: **there is no need to do this** for the sole reason you've described.

Comment: In the long run, people may do all sorts of things with that meta tag, like adding and removing 'seo' plugins that mess with it, and I wont't always be there to sort it out. A sort of futureproofing by redundancy one may call it. So is there any chance?

(pagination breaking shouldn't be an issue since this would only revert to the original wordpress behaviour)

Comment: You should ask "How do I prevent indexing on paginated archives?", this permalinks here but not there stuff is an XY issue and overcomplicated

Comment: [Philosophically speaking](http://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/580808-de-l-inconv-nient-d-tre-n), every issue is an AB..XY issue, one way or another ;) But i agree with the phrasing - How do I prevent indexing on paginated archives?